# Nashorn: use of source maps

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, typescript, nashorn

I'm currently using typescript for client side development and java for server side (Maven Project).
Now I'd like to create a @Parametrized JUnit test, which runs my typescript tests.
For now i am compiling the Typescript into the target/test-classes folder and load them via ScriptRunner using eval. In case of an exception, you get the stack trace of the js file. Does anyone know a way to use the ts files (so tell nashorn to use the resource map)? 
I would also like to ask if you know any way of debugging this (like jumping between js/ts and java code) inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nashorn supports //@sourceURL=foo [ and //#sourceURL=foo ] directive to set the source URL to be used for reported errors. Nashorn does not load/parse source maps. You need to explicitly map to source by reading javax.script.ScriptException or it's cause exception jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornException in your embedding code.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand you correctly, i have to map the source map manually? Do you know of an example I can look up?

Comment: Did a quick googling to hit this : https://github.com/mozilla/source-map. A javascript library to use source maps. I've not tried this on Nashorn - but if it is ECMAScript 5.1 compliant code, then it should run fine on Nashorn.